# Telerik table is repeating rows

Tags: telerik, telerik-mvc

I am using 2 tables in telerik report designer. These values should appear 1 time only. I'm not getting the point why I'm not getting them once.
Please if anybody can help please do I really need this to be done

[image]

These are the 2 tables I am using

[image]

This the returned data I am having.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you added a grouping? Does your data repeat?

Comment: Yes @Charleh I added grouping and it is repeating.

Comment: Can you show your data set and the grouping detail that you added?

Comment: Yes let me edit my question

Comment: @Charleh Please have a look now